# Mapbox fix Accuracy

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Im trying to make more accurate the mapbox lib in my react app .It shows me that i am like 10 miles away from my official location.

Any way to fix this ?
I enable hight Accuracy also but i got nothing.

Code :

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if (picarProfilePressed) {
        // Call your location function here
        locateUser();
        setPicarProfilePressed(false); // Reset the state
      }
    }, [picarProfilePressed]);

    const locateUser = () => {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          const userLat = position.coords.latitude;
          const userLng = position.coords.longitude;
  
          // Update marker position
          marker.current.setLngLat([userLng, userLat]);
          // Update map center and zoom
          map.current.flyTo({ center: [userLng, userLat], zoom: 11 , duration:1 , ease : (t) => t});
  
          // Update state
          setLng(userLng);
          setLat(userLat);
        }, (error) => {
          console.error("Error getting user's location:", error);
        },
        {enableHighAccuracy:true}
        );
      } else {
        console.error("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
      
    };
```